# redirect to new page of jquery validation passes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#value').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../validation.php',
            data: {
                validate_year:$('#Year').val(),
                validate_value:$('#value').val(),
                validate_domain:$('#Domain').val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        })
    });
});
```

in `validation.php` I have a sql statement which basically uses whatever is in `Year`, `value` and `domain` and then runs a select statement and the result is then rendering into a table in the same `validation.php` using echo `$something` in the table `<tr>`. What I want to do this display the `validation.php` to the user so the can see this table... because so they can make changes to it such as update and delete.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this

```
$(document).on('change', '#value', function() {
    $.post('/validation.php', {validate_year:$("#Year").val(), 
         validate_value:$("#value").val(), 
         validate_domain$("#Domain").val()}, function(data) {
       //Take the output of validation.php and put them into a class or id target
       $(".target-area").html(data);
  }
});
```

Basically what is happening is that the $.post function is reaching out to a URL that you specify, in this case validation.php.  I am guessing that you are trying to return something to the javascript file that indicates whether something is valid or not.  So for example

```
//valiation.php
<?php
$validate_year = $_POST['validate_year'];
$validate_value = $_POST['validate_value'];
$validate_domain = $_POST['validate_domain'];

//Do something here to determine if it is valid or not

//If the result is $valid in this pseudo code example
if($valid) {
   echo 'true';
} else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

In this example, the PHP script is returning a value of true or false based on the checks that you made against a database, expected results, etc, etc to the posted variable, in this case it is returned as the `data` variable in javascript.

So if you did something like this,

```
$(document).on('change', '#value', function() {
        $.post('/validation.php', {validate_year:$("#Year").val(), 
             validate_value:$("#value").val(), 
             validate_domain$("#Domain").val()}, function(data) {
           //Take the output of validation.php and log it to the console
           console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

You would see the `true` or `false` result from the validation.php file I wrote.  You probably want to return something to notify the user whether or not the validation failed or succeeded.  So to expand on this, say you had a div on your page setup like this

```
<div id="validation-result"></div>
```

Your javscript would interpret the response from validation.php and output something to the user ... like this

```
   $(document).on('change', '#value', function() {
            $.post('/validation.php', {validate_year:$("#Year").val(), 
                 validate_value:$("#value").val(), 
                 validate_domain$("#Domain").val()}, function(data) {
               //Take the output of validation.php, parse it and update the page
               if(data == 'true') {
                  var content = "Your validation succeeded";
               } else {
                  var content ="Your validation failed";
               }
               $("#validation-result").html(content);
          }
        });
```

And the final result on your page would look like this for true

```
<div id="validation-result">Your validation succeeded</div>
```

or this for false

```
<div id="validation-result">Your validaiton failed</div>
```

Hope that help clears up the answer a little bit for you

Comment: thanks for your reply but what will  `$(".target-area")` content?

Comment: I added on to my answer, hopefully that helps you understand it a little better.

Comment: If you are looking to redirect, you would add this to the your true/false statement window.location.href = "some-new-url"